US visa for EU residency card holders
I am a holder of a residency permit in France. As far as I understand I cannot apply for the Waiver Program US visa as I am not a citizen of France yet. Still Can I get a tourist visa in the US with my residency permit?

What is your citizenship? Do you have a valid passport or a travel document?

You can get a visa for the US without having a residence permit for France.

Your question is unclear. Do you mean ‘am I eligible to apply in France’ or ‘if I apply, will I get a visa’?

@xngtng

in Europe I travel with my carte de sejour (residency card), my citizenship is Russian.


@Traveller
my question was if i am allowed to aplply with residency permit for US tourist visa

"in Europe I travel with my carte de sejour (residency card": generally speaking you should have the passport in addition to your residence permit.  Some countries are stricter about this; Germany comes to mind.  If you are asked to identify yourself outside France and your passport isn't readily available, you might be fined.  Are you asking whether you can apply for a US visa by submitting your residence permit only, without also submitting your passport?


My question was if I am allowed to apply with residency permit for US tourist visa?

Yes
Unlike some jurisdictions, the US allows submission of a tourist visa application from any location where the applicant is legally present.
The process for applying for a non immigrant visa and a link to apply can be found on US Embassy & Consulates in France
As @phoog comments, for clarity, you will have to submit your passport with the application. You can't get a visa by submitting only a residence permit.

But she will have to submit her passport with the application; she can't get a visa by submitting only her residence permit.

@phoog Good call, I’ve amended my answer

The visa officials of most countries, including the US, want to let genuine tourists and business travelers in, and keep illegal immigrants, criminals, and some other categories out. They cannot know the true intentions of an applicant, they have to guess based on documents and their databases.
For someone with a residence and work permit in France and an average job, it would probably not be rational to give that up and become an illegal immigrant with an undocumented job in the US. So having a residence permit in France is likely to increase the chances of the US visa application.
Yet there are many reasons why the US might deny a visa. Original citizenship, previous visa records, a match in some database. We cannot know.

Of course i dont have any illegal intentions)))) i want to travel solely for tourist purpose

@YekaterinaTsanava, how can the visa officials know that? I believe you, but I don't have the problem if you overstay, the US does. The Americans do.
